# Wrong mv command. Where did my files go?

Tags: data-recovery, move

I used the command

```
mv folder_name ....
```

I thought by using `..` twice, it would move it back *two* folders.

Unfortunately my files disappeared.

I need to recover them.

Comment: `history | grep mv`  will show which command you have exactly use.

Comment: Don't worry, your files are safe in `....` !

Comment: I recommend always using mv -vi (and cp -avi) for this reason. For me, these flags are muscle memory.

Comment: you meant `../..`

Comment: @heemayl the canonical answer belongs here on Unix & Linux, not the Ubuntu Support Forum... err... branded Ubuntu SE.

Comment: Blame DOS where `...` means `..\..` and `....` means `..\..\..`, if I recall correctly.  Might be the same in Windows but I never used the latter.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Your directory is still there :)

You have renamed it `....`

Because files whose names start with `.` are hidden, you cannot see the directory unless you display hidden files

run

```
ls -A
```

and there it is!

Revert the change:

```
mv .... original_folder_name
```

and do the move correctly

```
mv original_folder_name ../..
```

Answer (score 41):

The correct form would have been

```
mv folder_name ../..
```

You've moved your folder to a new folder named `....`; to recover your files, run

```
mv .... folder_name
```

Like many other commands, `mv` is somewhat dangerous because mistakes can in some cases cause unrecoverable loss of data (except from backups): anything which ends up being interpreted as "move these files to this *file*" will cause all the files apart from the last one to be lost (each file will be renamed in turn to the target). To prevent such mistakes, there are a number of techniques:

- use `-i`, which tells `mv` to ask for confirmation before overwriting;
- use `-t` to specify the target folder (so `mv` will only move to a target folder);
- use a `/` at the end of the target folder's name.

Comment: It's a good job you didn't do "mv folder_name/* ....", as that would have been unrecoverable

Comment: $ mv dir/* .... ->
mv: target ‘....’ is not a directory

Comment: Aargh, why did you do that? pjc50 said it was a good job you *didn't* do that!

Comment: Ah actually it doesn't do anything...

Comment: @StephenKitt: No, but it's very dangerous because of what can happen if there are exactly 2 files and you hit enter before typing the `....`. For this reason I advise never to type commands of the form `mv dir/* dest`. Commands whose prefixes are dangerous operations are bad news.

Comment: @R.. Yes, I know why it's dangerous, hence my initial reaction. A decent safety net is to always add a trailing `/` or to use the `-t` option.

Comment: Aliasing `mv` to `mv -i` is also pretty standard. Some distros do it in their default profile.

Answer (score 7):

You just renamed your folder to `....`, and since it starts with `.`, it's now hidden.

type `mv .... foldername` to recover it

you can also type `ls -la` to list it (since `-a` prints hidden files)

The correct way to descend files and folder two directories is `mv fileorfolder ../../`

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, if you add a / to the end of the path, then the command will fail if the target isn't a pre-existing directory, for example 
`mv foldername ..../`

Comment: I did `mkdir foo; mv foo bar/` and it still worked.  `bar` didn't exist prior to that.